# ColdFusion Search

Tags: coldfusion, full-text-search, indexing

I’ve created a file index of all of my ColdFusion files so I can quickly search the files and find what I’m looking for. So far, it’s working great except it doesn’t seem to be searching inside any ColdFusion tags.

For example…

```
<p>If I searched for this text, It would return a result</p>
<cfset variables.foo = "however, If I search for this text it wouldn’t return any results." />
```

Does anyone know if there’s a way to search inside of a ColdFusion tag like that?

This is my index..

```
<cfindex 
   collection = "fileIndex"
   action="refresh"
   type="path"
   key="d:\my-websites-location\" 
   urlpath="http://mywebsite/"
   extensions=".cfm, .cfml, .cfc"
   recurse="Yes">
```

This is my search…

```
<cfsearch 
  name = "testSearch"
  collection = "fileIndex"
  type="internet"
  criteria = "variables.foo"
 />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Paul : )

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the type="internet" may be your issue. Try removing the "type" attribute and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query that does get the record and look at the "summary" field of your result. I suspect the markup is being stripped.

On ColdFusion 9, with solr it doesn't index the markup, however Verity does. A workaround you could use a combination of cffile/cfdirectory to read each file one by one and feed it into the collection. This will preserve the markup and make it searchable.

Comment: The summary includes the markup. I think it may be the cfsearch tag that's the issue. I've considered using cffile/cfdirectory however there's about 2000 files that it needs to index and it's a recursive index. I think this would be a difficult thing to do load wise. Thanks for the recommendation though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can enclose your criteria variable with ##.

```
<cfsearch 
name = "testSearch"
collection = "fileIndex"
type="internet"
criteria = "#variables.foo#"
/>
```